# Getting Error while writing data to csv file

Tags: python-2.7

```
def write_hms(hms):
    try:
    with open(FILENAME, "w", newline="") as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file,delimiter='|')
    writer.writerows(hms)

    except OSError as e:
        print(type(e), e)
        exit_program()
    except Exception as e:
        print(type(e), e)
        exit_program()
```

Get error:

> `<class '_csv.Error'>` iterable expected, not int
>   Terminating program.

Comment: Please edit your code so that it is correctly indented and state what output you expect. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is some more guidance

Comment: I expected that the input value are written in the csv file mentioned in the program.Inspite of indentation correctly done it does not work ..

Comment: def add_hm(hms):
    EmployerId = int(input("EmployerId"))
    Firstname = str(input("Firstname"))
    Middlename = str(input("Middlename"))
    Lastname = str(input("Lastname"))
    Gender =  str(input("Gender"))
    DateofBirth = int(input("DateofBirth"))
    ParticipantID = int(input ("ParticipantID"))
    hm = []
    hm.append(EmployerId)
    hm.append(Firstname)
    hm.append(Middlename)
    hm.append(Lastname)
    hm.append(DateofBirth)
    hm.append(Gender)
    hm.append(ParticipantID)
    hm.append(hm)
    write_hms(hm)
    print(Firstname + " was added.\n")

Answer (score 0):

You have not indented the code correctly but if I copy your code, indent it correctly and specify the variables that you have not defined (like `hms` and `FILENAME`) then the code runs without a problem.

```
import sys
import csv

FILENAME = 'test.csv'


def write_hms(hms):
    try:
        with open(FILENAME, "w", newline="") as file:
            writer = csv.writer(file,delimiter='|')
            writer.writerows(hms)
    except OSError as e:
        print(type(e), e)
        sys.exit(1)
    except Exception as e:
        print(type(e), e)
        sys.exit(1)


write_hms(['Spam'] * 5 + ['Baked Beans'])
```

The error you are getting suggest that you are not passing an 'iterable' like the csv writer is expecting but rather a `int`. Hence the problem is most likely with the input you are passing in `hms` and that you are not showing.

If this does not answer your question, please provide a complete, minimal example.